# java polymorphism code. level newbie

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'd like to separate some polymorphism example from the book into several files, but got an error with main class PoliWithClasses while creating objects emp1 and emp2 of classes Programmer and Manager. Please let me know what is wrong to make run the following code

File Employee.java

```
package po;

abstract class Employee {
    public void reachOffice() {
        System.out.println("reached Office - India");
    }
public abstract void startProject();
}
```

File Programmer.java

```
package po;

class Programmer extends Employee {
public void startProject(){
    defineClasses();
    unitTestCode();
}
private void defineClasses() {System.out.println("define classes");}
private void unitTestCode() {System.out.println("unit Test Code");}
}
```

File Manager.java

```
package po;

class Manager extends Employee {
    public void startProject() {
        meetingWithCustomer();
        defineProjectSchedule();
        assignRespToTeam();
    };
    private void meetingWithCustomer() {System.out.println("meet Customer");}
    private void defineProjectSchedule() {System.out.println("define Project Schedule");}
    private void assignRespToTeam() {System.out.println("assign Resp To Team");}
}
```

File PoliWithClasses.java

```
package po;

public class PoliWithClasses {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
    }
Employee emp1=new Programmer();
Employee emp2=new Manager();

emp1.reachOffice();
emp2.reachOffice();

emp1.startProjectWork();
emp2.startProjectWork();
}
```

---

Thanks, I have corrected the typo but still looks like these objects are not visible in main class:

```
emp1.reachOffice(); 
emp2.reachOffice();

emp1.startProject(); 
emp2.startProject();
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Is your method supposed to be called `startProject()` or `startProjectWork()` ?

Comment: Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at po.PoliWithClasses.main(PoliWithClasses.java:4)

Comment: Also I see these errors with created emp1 and emp2 objects: Syntax error on token "reachOffice", Identifier expected after this token    Syntax error on token "startProject", Identifier expected after this token

Comment: You put your main code outside the main method in that snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments on the given error message suggests this is the actual issue:

```
public class PoliWithClasses {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
    //} <-- your bracket was here
        Employee emp1=new Programmer();
        Employee emp2=new Manager();

        emp1.reachOffice();
        emp2.reachOffice();

        emp1.startProject(); // use consistent names
        emp2.startProject();
    } // the code must be contained in the method
}
```

To sum it up:

1. The first issue you found was an improper method call in the main code. This is not an issue related to polymorphism, since the method prototype of `startProject` in the subclasses matches with the one in `Employee`.
2. The actual code you wished to have executed was not inside the scope of `main`. The declarations of `emp1` and `emp2` were being interpreted as package-scoped field declarations. However, `emp1.reachOffice()` and `emp2.reachOffice()` are both illegal outside of a method's implementation.

I will also add a recommendation: use the @Override annotation every time a method is overridden in a child class (it makes sure that an override took place). For example, in your `Programmer` class:

```
class Programmer extends Employee {

    @Override
    public void startProject(){
        defineClasses();
        unitTestCode();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your code. Not:

`emp1.startProjectWork();
emp2.startProjectWork();`

but:

`emp1.startProject();
emp2.startProject();`